# Git Bash no color in laravel 5.1.25 artisan console

Tags: console, laravel-5, git-bash, laravel-artisan

no print color in artisan comands:(←[32m/ \033[32m)

```
 ←[32mview:clear←[39m
```

I'm use Windows 8.1 and git Bash last version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the below line under my *.bash_profile* or *.bashrc*:

```
# Fix Laravel artisan output
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Hope it helped!